# Loading image disappearing too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Pulling external pages into a `<div>`. I have a loading image while the content populates however it disappears to soon (before the content has loaded) and there is a few seconds gap before content has loaded. Any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/loader_large.gif'/>";
    $("#page_1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#content").html(ajax_load).load("page_1.html");
    });
    $("#page_2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#content").html(ajax_load).load("page_2.html");
    });
});
```

Comment: "a few seconds gap" how long does it take to load a single html file from the same domain ?

Comment: You can use a call back on the load that would hide the loading icon and avoid using a timeout for the loading image

Comment: @adeneo the html files are pulling instagram photos using jquery/ajax and instagrams API. It populates recent hastags, considerably fast overall. The load time takes roughly 2 to 3 seconds but the issue is the loader disappears to soon as the HTML file loads but the javascript is still fetching the data.

Comment: @RyanS can you elaborate on this?

Comment: then it would be best to edit the external html and handle the loading icon in the load completed callback for the ajax load on that page rather than on the "parent" page.

Comment: Your issue then isn't with loading the content, it's with the loaded contents ajax calls and large images, and that should be solved in the loaded content, not in the script that loads the content.

Comment: @adeneo thanks, worked a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to make your document aware of ajax calls via a separate handler. Then you would only have one place to manage your loading gif and get things appearing and disappearing in the order you want.

[Here is a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/98hNf/1).

To use in your example would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // removed your .html(ajax_load) in these
    $("#page_1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#content").load("page_1.html");
    });
    $("#page_2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#content").load("page_2.html");
    });

    // handlers for ajax events.
    // just make a hidden container with your loader in it and this will show/hide as necessary
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $(".ajax-load-container").show();
    }).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $(".ajax-load-container").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below and let me know:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
//    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/loader_large.gif'/>";
        var img = new Image();
        img.className = 'loading';
        img='img/loader_large.gif';
    img.onload = function(){
      $("#page_1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

       // $("#content").html(ajax_load).load("page_1.html");
        $("#content").append(img).load("page_1.html");
      });
      $("#page_2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
       // $("#content").html(ajax_load).load("page_2.html");
        $("#content").append(img).load("page_2.html");
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put hidden image into the `#content` element

```
    <div id="content"><img class='loading' style="display:none" src='img/loader_large.gif'/></div>
```

assuming your content is a div

and use `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` to hide and show it.

```
     $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $('.loading').hide();
        });
```

Comment: This would only work once as the loading img would be replaced with the ajax content. However, using this concept but showing/hiding a separate loading div I think would work (this loading div could be placed over the top of the #content div with css so it appears to occupy the same space).

Comment: @bbird didn't see he was overwritting the content. you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't count on counters because everything may happen and the counter may finish too soon.
I can't see where exactly you are removing the loading image. I suppose that it should be somewhere in .html files. But as you said there are ajax calls, which will finish after the page have been loaded so there will be a gap, as you said again. If all your ajax calls depend on each other then make them nested and remove the loading from very last one. In this way you  will be ensured that all the content is loaded. But it is more likely that these ajax calls are independent. Then you can make counter. Each time when some ajax call is ready you will increment the counter. When the counter is equal to number of your ajax calls then you will remove the loading image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones input, learned of some new methods, so thank you. I end up loading from the .js file that loads the instagram data. Works most effective this way and very simple, guess I have been awake too long (over thinking).

Below is an example of how I achieved it:

```
$.ajax({
dataType:'jsonp',
url:url,    
beforeSend:function(){ $('.loader').html("<img src='img/loader_large.gif'/>");},
complete:function(){ $('.loader').html(""); }
});
};
```

CSS

```
 .loader { text-align:center; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you load the content into a hidden div and then replace #content with it?

Something like this:

```
$(function()
{ 
    var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='img/loader_large.gif'/>";

    $("#page_1").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#content").html(ajax_load);
        var content = $('<div />').load("page_1.html");
        $('#content').html(content.html());
    });

    $("#page_2").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#content").html(ajax_load);
        var content = $('<div />').load("page_2.html");
        $('#content').html(content.html());
    });
});
```